# Instagram Ruby Gem Authorization Error

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, oauth-2.0, instagram

When I run the sample application from the instagram ruby gem github page located here:
https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem

I get the following error:

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"}
```

I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: You have to change   
config.client_id = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
config.client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"

with your own credentials.

Comment: John, I've done that. The problem is from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The URL that my ruby code was sending to instagram to authorize the app was

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=xxx&redirect_url=xxx&response_type=code
```

But instead it should have been:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=xxx&response_type=code
```

Do you notice the difference? 
In the query request the instagram module should have used the variable name **redirect_uri** instead of **redirect_url** to get the access tokens.